# Lack of training partner

Tags: boxing, self-training, beginner

I recently started my career as correctional officer, and these past 6 months have shown me I need to learn some type of self defense so that not only am more capable, controlled, and with the fight IQ to further my confidence to deal with specific reoccurring situations at my job.

With that being said, I was taking some lessons, but once my car broke down, and ended up getting scrapped after finding out the frame was messed up, I have not been able to go to the classes. I recently bought some stuff online to use at home, and I go to my neighborhood Y. However, I ran into the problem of not having a training partner to help with mitt training or sparring. What is the best way to train with the lack of training partners?

Answer (score 2):

The question asks how does a beginner level martial arts student continue training entirely on his own without a regular school to train at and without partners.

My simple answer is: Don't train martial arts on your own at all at this point as a beginner. Instead, consider working just on your physical conditioning for now.

The reason why I say not to train martial arts on your own is because you're a beginner level student who hasn't gotten enough correction to begin training on your own. That's important, because what happens with beginners who do this is that they drill the wrong technique into muscle memory, and it becomes a habit that's very hard to correct later on.

If you were to ask someone to partner with you on your own, that might also mean you hurt yourself or your partner by accident without the proper technique and without understanding how to do it safely.

It's far better to wait until you're being watched by a competent instructor who will see to it that your technique is good. That is crucial for all beginning level students.

I'd even go so far as to say everyone needs frequent correction, even advanced black belt students. It's bad even for them to do a lot of training on their own without anyone looking critically at their technique. Martial arts aren't simple exercises. They're very complex and require an experienced, careful eye watching you.

This is different from an instructor telling beginners to go home and practice something as homework before the next class. That's fine. In that case, you're still attending regular classes, and your instructor will make corrections when you go back to class. Practicing the wrong technique at home once or twice isn't going to mess you up. But if the student is no longer attending classes at all and is truly on his/her own, that's when bad habits become nearly permanent and hard to correct.

Be patient. Your life circumstances are temporary. You'll have opportunities to attend a martial arts school soon enough. In the meanwhile, doing physical conditioning won't be wasted time.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You may have misread the question. The OP wrote that they started a career as a correctional officer, not a police officer. There's often a big difference. Your recommendation of "putting more time in at the gun range" may not be as helpful as you intended. Because correctional officers are often in close proximity with inmates, most do not carry firearms. Given the OP's question, they are likely in close proximity with inmates. Also, when an officer relies on a firearm to feel confident, the result may lead to an avoidable tragedy, sometimes resulting in the officer becoming an inmate.

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate That's a good catch. I misread correctional officer as police officer.

Answer (score 0):

It you can find 1 person as a test subject for your techniques to practice is much better than nothing. A class is best of different body sizes and abilities to practice against. If you are trained at boxing you could do shadow boxing, a mirror is a great investment. you can also buy or make a  bag work to use for striking.

Answer (score -2):

Well, sadly i must say, this problem cant be fixed

If, somebody asks you for only one, thing that makes you a master

Then, you must say , what is facts in literature, that people call, history

Like, what you think is motive in literature

So, you understand that you cant repair definition here

And also, situations called, fight dont have Iq, because its theory

And, you see in theory you need, partner , in practice you cant find any

Because, if you show knife in such situation, you cant expect such person to withdraw

So, this is about places, where you can visit and play soccer for example

Or, basketball , because i live in poland

You should, remember one thing, that names like, aikido or taekwondo , exist only in books

Taekwondo , for example is way that really poor people, belive can bring some success

Techniques, in taekwondo are terribly poor, so i suggest watching movies because, martial arts is closer to dancing

In aikido you learn, shiho nage, or kote gaeshi, its far too simple to explain for example, Hsing - i, style of 12 animals

I personally, try to learn Baguazhang, which is 300 pages book, and its worth considering, if there is book that you can read because its things you can learn

Comment: I agree with the general idea that you can't practice fighting without fighting, but the rest of the answer is a bit incoherent.